# Python display .ply, .stl, .igs, .step image

Tags: python, opengl, blender, panda3d

I am looking for a way to display a .ply, .stl, .step, or .igs in a python window of any sort. The idea is that my students are moving a robot holding a part and i want to show that part also moving in 3d.

The formats listed above are the ones that i can produce.

I have explored Panda3D, OPenGL, Vpython and Blender. The only reason i dont use blender is because i want just a window and real-time.

Thanks for the help.

and if you have examples that would be just awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have tried using opengl in python and it is insufficient (or too much work) then blender is most likely your best choice. I would say your best option is to use the game engine and manipulate the model using keyboard input. You can have the game engine run full screen, or in a single window.

[This tutorial](http://www.warp1337.com/content/blender-robotics-part-1-introduction-and-modelling) on using blender for robotics can get you started and finishes with how to use Kinect to control the robot in the game engine.

[There is also this series](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMYtDzby1wdZIHi203Xv5aoxestpF1zX9) of short video tutorials on python scripting and the game engine that may interest you.

Blender now has it's [own stackexchange site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) where you will most likely have more luck getting blender specific help with any issues you come across.